# Multiple User idenity in nodejs sdk for Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am building a Hyperledger Fabric based web app. I am confused how to i manage user identity in HL.

There is multiple user in my web application and want to identify user in HL node sdk based api to perform the actions.

Also is there any example where i can use multiple user identity to invoke the api. With custom jwt authentication.

I found `composer-rest-server` is not helpful for me.

As i have to display some private data to authorised user and some public data to all.

Comment: if referring to Composer SDK based APIs, these resources/links/code examples may be of use to you https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#cardapis

Comment: Any boilerplate you know for getting started with node sdk ? @PaulO'Mahony

Answer (score 1):

1-you need to manage unique IDs of participants and save it to any database and this can be done by extending loopback user built-in model in this [link](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-built-in-models.html#user-model)
or with what ever NodeJS framework you`re going to use note that this will be depending on local authentication not oAuth2.

2-you have to handle concurrency issue by implement FIFO queue in your application to prevent concurrency failure.

3-in my application i make all participants by default pending to admin approval so you'll have the ability to control issue new identities and even revoke identities.

4-after admin approval the easy part invoking transactions will be done using the user ID which you have saved in database which will be used to get identity credentials to sign transactions.

finally all of this may fit you or not it depends on your business case.